# ReactJS - setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Similar questions here seem to be a result of scoping issues which isn't the case for me. I'm trying to create function handlers to set the state of my `App` component. These are bound to `App` and stored for re-usability.

```
createLinkHandler(link)
{
    let pageState = this._pages[link];

    this.linkHandlers[link] = (function(newState) {
        this.setState({'page': newState});
    }).bind(this._app, pageState);
}
```

Logging `this` within the function verifies that the function was bound correctly to my `App` component. So I did a simple test to verify if `setState()` worked under normal conditions (main.js):

```
var myApp = <App/>
myApp.setState({'page': 1});
```

In both cases above, I'm left with an `Uncaught TypeError: {this/myApp}.setState is not a function`

Logged output for `this`/`myApp`: https://s26.postimg.org/ejfxd1djd/Capture.png

---

Update (here is my `App` class):

```
export class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            'page': this._pages.LOGIN,
            'style': this._styles.DEFAULT
        };
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: You can't setState directly on the component like that.  Try it from within the component where it can access its state.

Comment: State is internal to the component: you are not supposed to set the state from outside the component. If you want to pass properties to the component, well there are properties ;).

Comment: The fact that it doesn't work in your second example says to me that your App component is a function component and not a React.Component dervitive. Can you post the implementation of your App class?

Comment: @JosephDitton Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to input the properties with the react component creation like this:

```js
class myApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(this.props);

    this.state = {
        'page': this._pages.LOGIN,
        'style': this._styles.DEFAULT,
        ...this.props // overrides defaults if existing
    }
    this.createLinkHandler = this.createLinkHandler.bind(this)
  }
  
  createLinkHandler(link)
  {
      // no underscore dongle
      let pageState = this.pages[link]; 
      // set new state only inside.
      // do whatever you want to do over here.
      this.setState({...state, xyz: 'test'}) 
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
        <NavBar { ...this.pages, this.createLinkHandler } />
    )
  
  }

}

class NavBar extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super(this.props)
    this.state = { ...this.props }
  }
  
  render() {
    // call on click the function this will then be executed in the app
    // context and there you can change the App state.
    <div>
      <a OnClick={this.props.createLinkHandler('linkxyz')} />
      <a OnClick={this.props.createLinkHandler('linkxyz')} />
      <a OnClick={this.props.createLinkHandler('linkxyz')} />
    </div>
  }

}

// creating the react class with 
// certain properties
const props = {page: 1}
var myApp = <App {...props} />
```

Now you have a start state with `{page:1}` and you can expand it by creating a link handler! Hope I could help you out a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to give some background to what I'm doing: My `App` component is the highest level component, and its state properties `page` and `style` determine which components get rendered on-screen and what css style they use (so this information propagates through all components on the webpage). `App` renders a custom `NavBar` whose links should change the `page` state of `App` and ultimately the components being rendered on screen. So it would seem intuitive to me to be able to change `App`'s state from its internal components, but as mentioned, this isn't possible

Comment: It would seem like an app manager of some description might be the best solution to catch any events that should modify the 'state' of my `App`, and pass on these changes through the `App`s `props`

Comment: No problem, but you can create a function locally and bind it to the scope (so this is being respected) and then you can call it in a lower component to change the state inside the upper one. I will change my solution to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions if you don't like doing manual binding in constructor. Arrow functions takes binding automatically and there won't be scope related issues

```
createLinkHandler = (link) =>
  {
      // no underscore dongle
      let pageState = this.pages[link]; 
      // set new state only inside.
      // do whatever you want to do over here.
      this.setState({...state, xyz: 'test'}) 
  }
```